# How to demonstrate a 32-bit MIPS with FPUs in a FPGA?

Tags: mips, verilog, fpga, system-verilog, mips32

I am a master student currently doing my final project, I am planning to design a 32-bit MIPS with a FPUs and implement in Altera DE2-115 FPGA board.

I almost finish the main MIPS core design, and I just have no ideal how am I going to demonstrate my design. Running a program and let my MIPS calculate a very precise pi and display in the LEDs?

Do you have any good ideas about how to demonstrate that design in FPGA? I want to  demo my FPUs as well, a cool idea will be very very appreciated.

Comment: Torture it with csmith.

Comment: I just google csmith, is that use to test compliers? My MIPS will not implement all different kinds of instructions. So i think I will need to modify the assembly language to make sure my instructions set covers every instructions generated by compiler.

Comment: It's both useful for compilers and hardware verification. Granted that your MIPS compiler is already pretty stable and well-tested, your csmith-generated code will be testing the quality of the hardware implementation. And csmith is very configurable, you can limit its output to whatever subset your hardware can handle.

Comment: The board has an LCD, right? Do some simple 3D wireframe object rotation.

Comment: The LCD sceen (not the LCD character display) is an add-on - not every board has one, though you can purchase them and attach them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

create a Test_module which gets input from switches. Based on the input value, pass the pre-defined command & data for your FPU to process & display_module gets processed data and puts to LED/LCD.

eg:
`input    command
     00      idle
     01      22/7
     10       7/22`